# do I understand this haskell code with fromIntegral correctly?

Tags: haskell

I (think) I fully understand why `6/(length [1,2,3])` does not work: length returns an int (`length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int`) and Int does not implement the `/` function.

One proposed solution, that works is `6/fromIntegral (length [1,2,3])`

This question is about **why** this solution works.

My conjecture is: the function `fromIntegral` (see: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numhask-0.6.0.2/docs/src/NumHask.Data.Integral.html#line-210) is implemented in multiple ways (non-explicitly, but still) so that it can receive many different types and return many different types. So, when compiling the code, haskell will choose amongst the possible return types and use the apropriate one (in this case, double or float).

Is my conjecture correct?

Any filling of the gaps in this explanation also appreciated

Comment: `(/)` has type `Floating a => a -> a -> a`, but `length` returns an `Int`, and an `Int` is *not* `Floating`, with `fromIntegral`, you convert can convert this `Int`, to any `Num` type.

Comment: `(/)` is defined by `Fractional`, not `Floating`.

Comment: `Fractional` is however *not* per se a `Float` or a `Double`, For example a `Num a => Ratio a` is also a `Fractional`.

Comment: The `Int` type does implement _division_, even though it does not implement the / operator. You might want to try something like `div 6 (length [1,2,3])`. Also functions `mod` and `divMod`.

Comment: One more point: the types are not choosed at run-time, they are choosed at compile time. And, as explained in chi's answer, if that is not possible, you still get a compile-time error.

Comment: Beware! The thing you linked is *completely* unrelated to the question -- it is a different function from a library, not the `fromIntegral` that is specified in the Report. The correct implementation is [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#fromIntegral).

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition is mostly correct.

Like any function which is polymorphic on the return type, `fromIntegral` will produce a value in whatever type is needed for the program to type check. Roughly speaking, it produces the type which is required by the context.

For instance, `fromIntegral someValue + (3 :: Double)` will make `fromIntegral` produce a `Double`, since that's what's needed for everything to type-check.

If, after type inference, Haskell still has no idea about which specific type to use, it usually raises an error, complaining about the ambiguity. As a major exception, when a numeric type is needed, instead of raising an error some "default" types are used. This exception is what makes `print 3` work without having to write `print (3 :: Integer)` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

`fromIntegral` has type `(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`, so you can get any type that implements `Num` that you need.

`(/)` has type `Fractional a => a -> a -> a`, and since `Fractional` is a subclass of `Num`, `fromIntegral` will be able to provide an appropriate type.

The only remaining point is what type `6 / ...` will actually return; the expression itself has type `Fractional a => a`. That will depend on the context in which the expression is validated. In GHCi, for example, it will simply default to `Double`, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

`fromIntegral` has type `forall a b. (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`. If you’re familiar with other languages, `forall a b.` is like `<A, B>` (Java, C#) or `template<typename A, typename B>` (C++): it introduces a scope for type variables for a generic function.

Normally the `forall` is left implicit, but you can display it with e.g. `:set -fprint-explicit-foralls` in GHCi and enable it in your code with the `ExplicitForAll` extension. (Note that `-fprint-explicit-foralls` will put curly braces around the type variables, which is not valid syntax; I’ll explain below.)

The type parameters `a` and `b` (as well as the constraints `Integral a` and `Num b`) are *arguments* passed in to the function by the *caller* of `fromIntegral`, but unlike value-level arguments, these type-level arguments are passed implicitly by the compiler at compile-time. When you write something like this:

```
6.0 / fromIntegral (length [1, 2, 3]) :: Double
```

`fromIntegral` is inferred as having the type arguments `Int` (because `length` returns an `Int`) and `Double` (because of the type annotation). So the type variables are filled in like so:

```
(Integral Int, Num Double) => Int -> Double
```

Then the compiler finds the definitions of `instance Integral Int` and `instance Num Double` and uses their implementations of `toInteger :: forall a. Integral a => a > Integer`) and `fromInteger :: forall a. Num a => Integer -> a` (specialised to `fromInteger :: Integer -> Double`) to do the conversion. And finally these call GHC primitive functions like `smallInteger` and `doubleFromInteger` that do the actual conversions.

With the `TypeApplications` extension you can write these type arguments explicitly:

```
> :set -fprint-explicit-foralls

> :t fromIntegral -- original function
fromIntegral :: forall {a} {b}. (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b

> :t fromIntegral @Int -- applied to one type argument
fromIntegral @Int :: forall {b}. Num b => Int -> b

> :t fromIntegral @Int @Double -- applied to both type arguments
fromIntegral @Int @Double :: Int -> Double

> :t fromIntegral @Int @Double 5 -- both type arguments *and* value argument
fromIntegral @Int @Double 5 :: Double
```

`TypeApplications` is the reason that `-fprint-explicit-foralls` sometimes prints curly braces `{}` around the type variables in a `forall` quantifier: the order of type arguments is defined by the type signature, and the curly braces indicate that there was a type signature specifying which type arguments you can fill in with `TypeApplications`. If there are no braces, then there was no signature, and you can’t use `TypeApplications` because the argument order isn’t specified.

It will *always* print braces when you use `:type` / `:t` because this command infers the type of an *expression*; if you want to know the *signature* of a definition, you need to use `:type +v` / `:t +v` instead. For example:

```
> :set -XTypeApplications -fprint-explicit-foralls

> example1 x y = x

> example2 :: a -> b -> a; example2 x y = x

> :t example1 -- always prints braces
example1 :: forall {p1} {p2}. p1 -> p2 -> p1

> :t example2 -- always prints braces
example2 :: forall {a} {b}. a -> b -> a

> :t +v example1 -- definition has no signature; prints braces
example1 :: forall {p1} {p2}. p1 -> p2 -> p1

> :t +v example2 -- definition has a signature; no braces
example2 :: forall a b. a -> b -> a
```

You can use `TypeApplications` with `example2` but not `example1`:

```
> :t example2 @Int @Char
example2 @Int @Char :: Int -> Char -> Int

> :t example1 @Int @Char

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Cannot apply expression of type ‘p10 -> p20 -> p10’
      to a visible type argument ‘Int’
    • In the expression: example1 @Int @Char
```